# Utilizando o json do firebase

Tags: firebase

Como eu posso fazer, por exemplo: há rotas, e nas rotas há pontos, e cada ponto da "tabela" ponto tem um idRota, que identifica a rota a qual ele pertence. Eu sei fazer isso em relacionais, mas com essa arvore de json não faço ideia

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro temos as **rotas**
depois -> **Subrotas** -> **ID_ROTA**
3 níveis.

```
{
   "Rotas":
   [ 
      { "sub_rota1":[ "ID_ROTA" ] }, 
      { "sub_rota2":[ "ID_ROTA" ] }, 
      { "sub_rota3":[ "ID_ROTA" ] } 
   ]
}
```

---